# Publishing Pusher Event To Specific User In .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pusher

I have a Pusher implementation that sends "MyEventName" messages:

```
var eventName = "MyEventName";
pusher.TriggerAsync(/*channel*/, eventName, "My Data To Send")
```

However, I only want to message going to a specific user.

I thought of just publishing to:

```
var eventName = "MyEventName" + "some uniquely identifying token";
```

...but is there a better, more supported way?

Comment: that would work, you could also have a unique channel for each user and have them subscribe to their respective channel.